# Отправка файла в Google drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive

Здравствуйте, подобные вопросы уже были но всё таки попробую спросить.

В андроид приложении необходимо сделать отправку файла в Google Диск. Пробовал делать по этой [инструкции](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro).

1. Зарегистрировал приложение в консоли разработчика (указываешь `sha1`, имя пакета...). Создавал и `API` ключ и идентификатор клиента `OAuth` 2.0
2. В официальной документации предлагают делать так:

**в build.gradle:**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'
```

**в манифесте:**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

**для соединения с Google диском:**

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

**при ошибке соединения:**

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Unable to resolve, message user appropriately
        }
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
    }
}
```

**и далее:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        ...
        case RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что мне необходимо сделать настройку в программе, чтобы выбирали аккаунт гугла, сохранять его, а потом при соединении указывать его для доступа к диску. Пробовал добавить `.setAccountName(имя_аккаунта_из_настроек)` при создании клиента, но такой вариант не прокатывает, `isConnected()` клиента после `connect()` равен `false`.

**Выбор аккаунта в настройках делаю так:**

```
Intent googlePicker = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
            new String[] { GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE }, true, null, null, null, null);
mActivity.startActivityForResult(googlePicker, PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);
```

здесь `mActivity` это активити (настройки программы) из которой вызываю окно с аккаунтами.

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать возможность соединения с диском гугл без необходимости вызывать окно выбора аккаунта при соединении с диском, а с помощью указанного в настройках программы аккаунта гугл. Причём аккаунт будет разный, тот который у пользователя добавлен в системе (возможно один из нескольких). Сейчас у меня получается даже если `isConnected() = false`, то отправка на мой диск, где я регистрировал приложение (консоль) выполняется. С другого аккаунта нет, и ошибка соединения всегда `ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED`...

P.S. бьюсь над этой задачей уже давно, пробовал и через Google APIs Java Client, этот вариант вообще не получается, материалов перерыл кучу, уже отчаялся сделать такую вроде бы простую функцию